# Фигурные скобки внутри метода и временные переменные

Tags: c#

```
    public static void Metod()
    {
        string url;
        {
            url = строка;
            int a1 = число;
            int a2 = число;
            url = операция над a1 и a2;
        }
        ....
        операции над url;
        ....
    }
```

В моем случае переменные a1 и a2 будут удалены из памяти перед "операциями над url;" ?

или нет?

Comment: а какая разница? Что бы с ними не произошло, вы ими уже не воспользуетесь, так?

Comment: @tym32167 после закрытия первой фигурной скобки они мне потом и не нужны. Вопрос в том: будут ли они занимать в памяти место?

Comment: Я не думаю, что это где то определено, но вы можете покопаться в документации в CLR. Предполагаю, что пока вы находитесь в той же функции, все объявленные переменные в этой функции живы. Как только вы покинете функцию, неиспользуемые переменные (по крайней мере для значимых типов) будут из памяти удалены.

Comment: Эти переменные лежат на стеке и при выходе за пределы блока указатель на вершину стека будет сдвинут, что сделает память, в которой лежали эти переменные доступной для использования. Но это низкоуровневые детали реализации, чисто с точки зрения синтаксиса языка, переменные объявленные внутри блока недоступны за его пределами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменные доступны в рамках контекста, в котором они определены. 
Это может быть:

- Класс/структура
- Метод
- Блок кода (фигурные скобки внутри метода)

Переменные класса доступны в любом месте внутри класса. Переменная метода только в методе. И соответственно переменная блока кода только внутри блока кода.

Да, вы правы, перед "операция на url" они будут не будут доступны, а память освобождена или объекты будут удалены сборщиком мусора как только на них перестанут ссылаться

Comment: Разве `int`ы обрабатываются сборщиком мусора? Он вроде только для классов же

Comment: Да, верно. Исправился. Но сути не изменилось - по завершению блока память будет освобождена